# Docker - orchardup/mysql container does not start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker

Found a strange problem with orchardup/mysql container, which is one of the most starred trusted mysql containers.
Container does not start on ubuntu host.

I've tried to run it on Ubuntu 14.04 using:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass orchardup/mysql
```

Container is not visible with:

```
docker.io ps
```

It is visible using:

```
docker.io ps -a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default version of Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 is version 0.9.
You can try to use newest docker version:

```
deb https://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main
```

And install a package with:

```
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker.
```

You can also change the default driver to the devicemapper by adding line below to /etc/default/docker

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"
```